# Exclude particular DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

**Customers Table:**

```
CustomerID;CustomerName;BatchDeadline
1;AAA;1
2;BBB;2
3;CCC;2
4;DDD;3
```

*BatchDeadline: Number of days after BatchDate, if 2 means second day of BatchDate in Batches table.

**Batches Table:**

```
BatchID;CustomerID;BatchDate
1;1;2015-03-02 8:00
2;2;2015-03-02 8:10
3;2;2015-03-03 10:20
4;1;2015-03-04 11:10
5;3;2015-03-04 11:12
6;3;2015-03-04 19:22
7;3;2015-03-05 11:23
```

I am trying to get number of batches that passed deadline, and number of batches near deadline (2 hours before the deadline).

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
foreach(customer c in customers)
{
  foreach(Batch b in batches) 
  {
     DateTime deadline = b.BatchDate.AddDays(c.BatchDate);
     DateTime nearDeadline = deadline.AddHours(-2);

     if (now > deadline) {
        // passed the deadline
     } else if (now >= nearDeadline) {
        // near the deadline
     }
  }
}
```

The above code works fine when I check in 24 hours time. How about when it is required to check just from 8am - 4pm?

To make it clear: I want to exlude evening time, just include office hours. Check for batches that passed deadline and near deadline just within office hours 8am to 4pm.

Comment: `java` tag seems irrelevant. I deleted it. How about checking their `TimeOfDay` properties which is `TimeSpan`? Or their `Hour` properties which is an `int`?

Comment: It's not clear what value you're wanting to check - but surely `if (x.Hour < 8 || x.Hour > 16)` would do the job...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am checking c.BatchDate

Comment: So where does `now` come in? And does `batch.BatchDate.Hour < 8` (etc) not do what you want? (It doesn't help that in your sample code you're using `batch.BatchDate` when `batch` doesn't exist, which suggests this isn't actually code you've compiled...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: oh, it should be b.BatchDate date. I have corrected it

Comment: And the rest of my question, about just using the `Hour` property?